# iOS Multiple UIPickerView Only Showing 1 view

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have 1 Viewcontroller with 5 UIPickerView in. The idea is that when each select button is pressed the pickerview is called and then a separate button shows the result picked. The problem I have is that no matter what button is selected and what UIPickerView is chosen the only button that changes is the final one. The only UIPickerView that is showing is the final as well until you press the last button and it shows the 1st and last UIPickerView at the same time.

**UPDATE**

Code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>{

        UITextField *nameTextField;
        UITextField *emailTextField;
        UITextField *dateTextField;
        UITextField *timeTextField;
        UITextField *blankTextField;
        UITextField *blankbTextField;
        UITextView  *messageTextView;

    UIPickerView *categoryTypePicker;
    UIPickerView *locationTypePicker;
    UIPickerView *originatorTypePicker;
    UIPickerView *destinationTypePicker;
    UIPickerView *statusTypePicker;
    UIButton *categoryTypeBtn;
    UIButton *locationTypeBtn;
    UIButton *originatorTypeBtn;
    UIButton *destinationTypeBtn;
    UIButton *statusTypeBtn;
    NSArray *categoryTypes;
    NSArray *locationTypes;
    NSArray *originatorTypes;
    NSArray *destinationTypes;
    NSArray *statusTypes;


    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    IBOutlet UILabel *mlabelcategory;
    NSMutableArray *arrayNocategory;
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerViewcategory;

        MFMailComposeViewController *email;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) MFMailComposeViewController *email;

    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *emailTextField;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *dateTextField;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *timeTextField;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *blankTextField;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *blankbTextField;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *mlabelcategory;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *messageTextView;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *categoryTypePicker;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *locationTypePicker;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *originatorTypePicker;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *destinationTypePicker;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *statusTypePicker;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *categoryTypeBtn;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *locationTypeBtn;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *originatorTypeBtn;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *destinationTypeBtn;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *statusTypeBtn;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *categoryTypes;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *locationTypes;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *originatorTypes;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *destinationTypes;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *statusTypes;






    @property NSString *name;
    @property NSString *emailaddress;
    @property NSString *date;
    @property NSString *time;
    @property NSString *blank;
    @property NSString *blankb;
    @property NSString *category;
    @property NSString *message;


    - (IBAction)checkData:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender;
    -(IBAction) showCategoryTypePicker;
    -(IBAction) showLocationTypePicker;
    -(IBAction) showOriginatorTypePicker;
    -(IBAction) showDestinationTypePicker;
    -(IBAction) showStatusTypePicker;

    - (void)sendMail;

@end
```

.m code

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

#define GeoLocation TRUE // FALSE for no latitude/longitude information
#define kPICKERCOLUMN 1
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PickerType) {
    CATEGORY_PICKER,
    LOCATION_PICKER,
    ORIGINATOR_PICKER,
    DESTINATION_PICKER,
    STATUS_PICKER
};

#define kPICKERCOLUMN 1
#define kPICKER_TAG     101

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    UIPickerView *picker;
    PickerType pickerType;
}
@synthesize nameTextField, emailTextField, dateTextField, timeTextField, blankTextField, blankbTextField, mlabelcategory, messageTextView, categoryTypes, locationTypes, originatorTypes, destinationTypes, statusTypes;
@synthesize name, emailaddress, date, time, blank, blankb, category, message, email, categoryTypeBtn, locationTypeBtn, originatorTypeBtn, destinationTypeBtn, statusTypeBtn;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        categoryTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Appetizers",@"Breakfast",@"Dessert",@"Drinks",
                         @"Main Dish/Entree", @"Salad", @"Side Dish", @"Soup", @"Snack",
                         @"Baby Food", @"Pet Food",nil];

        locationTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue"
                         ,nil];

        originatorTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                           nil];


        destinationTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                            nil];


        statusTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                       nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



    nameTextField.text = nil;
    emailTextField.text = nil;
    dateTextField.text = nil;
    timeTextField.text = nil;
    blankTextField.text = nil;
    blankbTextField.text = nil;
    mlabelcategory.text = nil;
    messageTextView.text = nil;

    picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,400,160)];
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:picker];
}


/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations.
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 */
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)eve
{
    picker.hidden = YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark picker methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return kPICKERCOLUMN;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    switch (pickerType) {
        case CATEGORY_PICKER:
            return [categoryTypes count];;
            break;
        case LOCATION_PICKER:
            return [locationTypes count];
            break;
        case ORIGINATOR_PICKER:
            return [originatorTypes count];
            break;
        case DESTINATION_PICKER:
            return [destinationTypes count];
            break;
        case STATUS_PICKER:
            return [statusTypes count];
            break;
        default: return -1;
            break;
    }

}



- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (pickerType) {
        case CATEGORY_PICKER:
            return [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case LOCATION_PICKER:
            return [locationTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case ORIGINATOR_PICKER:
            return [originatorTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case DESTINATION_PICKER:
            return [destinationTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case STATUS_PICKER:
            return [statusTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        default: return nil;
            break;

    }
}




- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (pickerType) {
        case CATEGORY_PICKER: {
            NSString *categoryType  = [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            [categoryTypeBtn setTitle:categoryType forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;
        }
        case LOCATION_PICKER: {

            NSString *locationType  = [locationTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            [locationTypeBtn setTitle:locationType forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;

        }
        case ORIGINATOR_PICKER: {
            NSString *originatorType  = [originatorTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            [originatorTypeBtn setTitle:originatorType forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;
        }
        case DESTINATION_PICKER: {
            NSString *destinationType  = [destinationTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            [destinationTypeBtn setTitle:destinationType forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;
        }
        case STATUS_PICKER:{
            NSString *statusType  = [statusTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            [statusTypeBtn setTitle:statusType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
-(IBAction) showLocationTypePicker{

    pickerType = LOCATION_PICKER;
    picker.hidden = NO;
    [picker reloadAllComponents];

}
-(IBAction) showCategoryTypePicker{
    pickerType = CATEGORY_PICKER;
    picker.hidden = NO;
    [picker reloadAllComponents];
}

-(IBAction) showOriginatorTypePicker{
    pickerType = ORIGINATOR_PICKER;
    picker.hidden = NO;
    [picker reloadAllComponents];
}

-(IBAction) showDestinationTypePicker{
    pickerType = DESTINATION_PICKER;
    picker.hidden = NO;
    [picker reloadAllComponents];
}

-(IBAction) showStatusTypePicker{
    pickerType = STATUS_PICKER;
    picker.hidden = NO;
    [picker reloadAllComponents];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

#pragma - getting info from the UI

//NSString *test = nil;


- (IBAction)checkData:(id)sender
{
    /*
     name = nameTextField.text;
     surname = surnameTextField.text;
     bornDate = bornDateTextField.text;
     address = addressTextField.text;
     zipCode = zipTextField.text;
     email = emailTextField.text;
     */

    //NSLog(@" Name: %@ \n Surname: %@ \n Date of Birth: %@ \n Address: %@ \n Post Code: %@ \n email: %@ \n", name, surname, bornDate, address, zipCode, email);

    unsigned int x,a = 0;
    NSMutableString *emailmessage; //stringa variabile
    emailmessage = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @""]; //le stringhe mutabili vanno inizializzate in questo modo!


    for (x=0; x<7; x++)
    {
        switch (x) {
            case 0:
                if (nameTextField.text == nil) {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Name, "];
                    a=1;

                }
                break;

            case 1:
                if (emailTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Email Address, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                if (dateTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Date of Near Miss, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                if (timeTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Time of Near Miss, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 4:
                if (blankTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Post Code, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 5:
                if (blankbTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Email, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 6:
                if (mlabelcategory.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Category, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                if (messageTextView.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Observation Description, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

        {
        name = nameTextField.text;
        emailaddress = emailTextField.text;
        date = dateTextField.text;
        time = timeTextField.text;
        blank = blankTextField.text;
        blankb = blankbTextField.text;
        category = mlabelcategory.text;
        message = messageTextView.text;

        NSMutableString *nearmissreport;
        nearmissreport = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"<br><br> <b>Name:</b> %@ <br> <b>Email Address:</b> %@ <br> <b>Date of Near Miss:</b> %@ <br> <b>Time of Near Miss:</b> %@ <br> <b>Post Code:</b> %@ <br> <b>Email Address:</b> %@ <br> <b>Category:</b> %@ <br><b>Observation Description:</b> %@ <br>", name, emailaddress, date, time, blank, blankb, category, message];

        NSLog(@"Near Miss Report: %@", nearmissreport);

        NSMutableString *testoMail;
        testoMail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: nearmissreport];

        NSLog(@"%@", testoMail);


        //MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        MFMailComposeViewController  *pv = [[MFMailComposeViewController  alloc] init];
        pv.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [pv setSubject: name];

        // Set up the recipients.
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"paul.haddell@bbmmjv.com",nil];

        //NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com",@"third@example.com", nil];
        //NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"four@example.com",nil];

        [pv setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        //[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];
        //[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

        // Attach an image to the email.
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"" ofType:@"png"];
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [pv addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@""];

        // Fill out the email body text.
        //NSMutableString *emailBody;
        testoMail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%@", testoMail];

        [pv setMessageBody:testoMail isHTML:YES]; //HTML!!!!!!

        // Present the mail composition interface.
        [self presentViewController:pv animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}


// The mail compose view controller delegate method
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                        error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Mandare email
/*
 - (void)sendMail:(NSMutableString*)testoMail{

 MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

 [picker setSubject:@"Reclutamento pompieri"];

 // Set up the recipients.
 NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"reda.bousbah@gmail.com",nil];
 //NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com",@"third@example.com", nil];
 //NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"four@example.com",nil];

 [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
 //[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];
 //[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

 // Attach an image to the email.
 //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ipodnano" ofType:@"png"];
 //NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
 //[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"ipodnano"];

 // Fill out the email body text.
 NSString *emailBody = @"It is raining in sunny California!";
 [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

 // Present the mail composition interface.
 [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];


 }
 */



#pragma mark - methods to control the keyboard

- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender //method for resign the keyboard when the background is tapped
{
    [nameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [emailTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [dateTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [timeTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [blankTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [blankbTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [mlabelcategory resignFirstResponder];
    [messageTextView resignFirstResponder];

}

- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog( @"done button pressed");
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

Comment: Hey, looking at the code... it seems like when a button is clicked you call one of the 5 methods that starts with "showSomethingPicker". Each of this will unhide the all the other pickers and in that case, you will see the last picker since all of them have same position

Comment: Thank you! Stupid mistake really wasn't it!

Comment: If you don't mind, I would like to make a suggestion.
Your code will have only one picker displayed at any given time. I would suggest you to just create one picker instance and reuse the same instance. Regarding the content for the picker, you can use a global variable to set what type is clicked by the user which you can set in showSomethingPicker button action.

Comment: Hi @AshishMusale I dont suppose you know of any good examples that you can direct me too?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have any example. I could try to send you something with your case. Unfortunately I don't have your code running because of the missing pieces.

Comment: I will add all files. Thank you.

Comment: You should just implement one picker, understand how the delegate and data source methods work. Then you can reuse the same picker instead of creating 5 (which is really not recommended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. This is just an example, you have to make changes to make it work for your app

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

#define GeoLocation TRUE // FALSE for no latitude/longitude information
#define kPICKERCOLUMN 1
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PickerType) {
    CATEGORY_PICKER,
    LOCATION_PICKER,
    ORIGINATOR_PICKER,
    DESTINATION_PICKER,
    STATUS_PICKER
};

#define kPICKERCOLUMN 1
#define kPICKER_TAG     101

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    UIPickerView *picker;
    PickerType pickerType;
}
@synthesize nameTextField, emailTextField, dateTextField, timeTextField, blankTextField, blankbTextField, mlabelcategory, messageTextView;
@synthesize name, emailaddress, date, time, blank, blankb, category, message, email;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        categoryTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Appetizers",@"Breakfast",@"Dessert",@"Drinks",
                         @"Main Dish/Entree", @"Salad", @"Side Dish", @"Soup", @"Snack",
                         @"Baby Food", @"Pet Food",nil];

        locationTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue"
                         ,nil];

        originatorTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                           nil];


        destinationTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                            nil];


        statusTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                       nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



    nameTextField.text = nil;
    emailTextField.text = nil;
    dateTextField.text = nil;
    timeTextField.text = nil;
    blankTextField.text = nil;
    blankbTextField.text = nil;
    mlabelcategory.text = nil;
    messageTextView.text = nil;

    picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,400,160)];
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:picker];
}


/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations.
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 */
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)eve
{
    picker.hidden = YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark picker methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return kPICKERCOLUMN;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    switch (pickerType) {
        case CATEGORY_PICKER:
            return [categoryTypes count];;
            break;
        case LOCATION_PICKER:
            return [locationTypes count];
            break;
        case ORIGINATOR_PICKER:
            return [originatorTypes count];
            break;
        case DESTINATION_PICKER:
            return [destinationTypes count];
            break;
        case STATUS_PICKER:
            return [statusTypes count];
            break;
        default: return -1;
            break;
    }

}



- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (pickerType) {
        case CATEGORY_PICKER:
            return [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case LOCATION_PICKER:
            return [locationTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case ORIGINATOR_PICKER:
            return [originatorTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case DESTINATION_PICKER:
            return [destinationTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case STATUS_PICKER:
            return [statusTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        default: return nil;
            break;

    }
}




- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (pickerType) {
        case CATEGORY_PICKER: {
            NSString *categoryType  = [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            [categoryTypeBtn setTitle:categoryType forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;
        }
        case LOCATION_PICKER: {

            NSString *locationType  = [locationTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            [locationTypeBtn setTitle:locationType forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;

        }
        case ORIGINATOR_PICKER: {
            NSString *originatorType  = [originatorTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            [originatorTypeBtn setTitle:originatorType forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;
        }
        case DESTINATION_PICKER: {
            NSString *destinationType  = [destinationTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            [destinationTypeBtn setTitle:destinationType forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;
        }
        case STATUS_PICKER:{
            NSString *statusType  = [statusTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            [statusTypeBtn setTitle:statusType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
-(IBAction) showLocationTypePicker{

    pickerType = LOCATION_PICKER;
    picker.hidden = NO;
    [picker reloadAllComponents];

}
-(IBAction) showCategoryTypePicker{
    pickerType = CATEGORY_PICKER;
    picker.hidden = NO;
        [picker reloadAllComponents];
}

-(IBAction) showOriginatorTypePicker{
    pickerType = ORIGINATOR_PICKER;
    picker.hidden = NO;
    [picker reloadAllComponents];
}

-(IBAction) showDestinationTypePicker{
    pickerType = DESTINATION_PICKER;
    picker.hidden = NO;
    [picker reloadAllComponents];
}

-(IBAction) showStatusTypePicker{
    pickerType = STATUS_PICKER;
    picker.hidden = NO;
    [picker reloadAllComponents];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

#pragma - getting info from the UI

//NSString *test = nil;


- (IBAction)checkData:(id)sender
{
    /*
     name = nameTextField.text;
     surname = surnameTextField.text;
     bornDate = bornDateTextField.text;
     address = addressTextField.text;
     zipCode = zipTextField.text;
     email = emailTextField.text;
     */

    //NSLog(@" Name: %@ \n Surname: %@ \n Date of Birth: %@ \n Address: %@ \n Post Code: %@ \n email: %@ \n", name, surname, bornDate, address, zipCode, email);

    unsigned int x,a = 0;
    NSMutableString *emailmessage; //stringa variabile
    emailmessage = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @""]; //le stringhe mutabili vanno inizializzate in questo modo!


    for (x=0; x<7; x++)
    {
        switch (x) {
            case 0:
                if (nameTextField.text == nil) {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Name, "];
                    a=1;

                }
                break;

            case 1:
                if (emailTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Email Address, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                if (dateTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Date of Near Miss, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                if (timeTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Time of Near Miss, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 4:
                if (blankTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Post Code, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 5:
                if (blankbTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Email, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 6:
                if (mlabelcategory.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Category, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                if (messageTextView.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Observation Description, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    NSLog (@"Email Message: %@", emailmessage);

    if (a == 1) {

        NSMutableString  *popupError;
        popupError = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"Per inviare compilare i seguenti campi:  "];

        [popupError appendString:emailmessage]; //aggiungo i miei errori
        [popupError appendString: @" grazie della comprensione."]; //

        NSLog(@"%@", popupError);

        UIAlertView *chiamataEffettuata = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                           initWithTitle:@"ATTENTION" //titolo del mio foglio
                                           message:popupError
                                           delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok, correggo" //bottone con cui si chiude il messaggio
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [chiamataEffettuata show]; //istanza per mostrare effettivamente il messaggio
    }

    else
    {
        name = nameTextField.text;
        emailaddress = emailTextField.text;
        date = dateTextField.text;
        time = timeTextField.text;
        blank = blankTextField.text;
        blankb = blankbTextField.text;
        category = mlabelcategory.text;
        message = messageTextView.text;

        NSMutableString *nearmissreport;
        nearmissreport = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"<br><br> <b>Name:</b> %@ <br> <b>Email Address:</b> %@ <br> <b>Date of Near Miss:</b> %@ <br> <b>Time of Near Miss:</b> %@ <br> <b>Post Code:</b> %@ <br> <b>Email Address:</b> %@ <br> <b>Category:</b> %@ <br><b>Observation Description:</b> %@ <br>", name, emailaddress, date, time, blank, blankb, category, message];

        NSLog(@"Near Miss Report: %@", nearmissreport);

        NSMutableString *testoMail;
        testoMail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: nearmissreport];

        NSLog(@"%@", testoMail);


        //MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        MFMailComposeViewController  *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController  alloc] init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [picker setSubject: name];

        // Set up the recipients.
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"paul.haddell@bbmmjv.com",nil];

        //NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com",@"third@example.com", nil];
        //NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"four@example.com",nil];

        [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        //[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];
        //[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

        // Attach an image to the email.
        //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ipodnano" ofType:@"png"];
        //NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        //[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"ipodnano"];

        // Fill out the email body text.
        //NSMutableString *emailBody;
        testoMail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%@", testoMail];

        [picker setMessageBody:testoMail isHTML:YES]; //HTML!!!!!!

        // Present the mail composition interface.
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}


// The mail compose view controller delegate method
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                        error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Mandare email
/*
 - (void)sendMail:(NSMutableString*)testoMail{

 MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

 [picker setSubject:@"Reclutamento pompieri"];

 // Set up the recipients.
 NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"reda.bousbah@gmail.com",nil];
 //NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com",@"third@example.com", nil];
 //NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"four@example.com",nil];

 [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
 //[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];
 //[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

 // Attach an image to the email.
 //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ipodnano" ofType:@"png"];
 //NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
 //[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"ipodnano"];

 // Fill out the email body text.
 NSString *emailBody = @"It is raining in sunny California!";
 [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

 // Present the mail composition interface.
 [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];


 }
 */



#pragma mark - methods to control the keyboard

- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender //method for resign the keyboard when the background is tapped
{
    [nameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [emailTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [dateTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [timeTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [blankTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [blankbTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [mlabelcategory resignFirstResponder];
    [messageTextView resignFirstResponder];

}

- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog( @"done button pressed");
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

Comment: Sorry.I really appreciate all your help, its not showing any pickerviews now when the button is selected. Sorry.

Comment: try adding "picker.reloadAllComponents" to the button action after setting the picker type and unhiding it

Comment: I've added it after "picker.hidden = NO;" with no joy. In fact it states that it is unused when i add it.

Comment: Th pickerview is now showing however it has gone back to not showing any arrays within the pickerview.

Comment: I was able to see the data for each of the button actions with the code I sent. You need to debug now to find out if you are getting the correct array and that it is not empty

Comment: Really sorry but i'm pulling my hair out over this. I've copied it all into my app and its still coming up with no arrays. I've edited my code. Is there any chance you could have a look for me and see what i've done wrong?

Comment: Sure, i will see if i can create a git repo tonight with my code and share so u can see whats working for me

Comment: Thank you so much! I really do appreciate it!!

Comment: Thanks @AshishMusale. Thats exactly how I had my other app that was working. However when I copy the whole thing into my app it just doesn't want to show the arrays. The only thing that I can see thats different is that the app i am putting them into is an iPad app. Would this make a difference at all?

Comment: You need to debug the issue, not sure what the issue is.

Comment: would it be possible if I uploaded my app onto dropbox and share the link so that you can have a look at where I am going wrong?

Comment: Thank you very much!! Hopefully the link works https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bhp5ealq3s4zuu2/AADswxZa5DU4r8-XM63UAFnWa/Test

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot open this project

Comment: It should be working. I'll try and find another way to get the app to you.

Comment: Does this link work? https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bhp5ealq3s4zuu2/AADswxZa5DU4r8-XM63UAFnWa/Test

Comment: That didn't work either, there are no source code files in that project